# HTTP methods for the Django Rest Framework Viewset

Tags: django

I'm working on django rest framework viewset and want to know which HTTP methods map to the functions:

1.list()

2.create()

3.retrieve()

4.update()

5.partial_update()

6.destroy()

I have searched a lot but I didn't got the specific answer to my question.

So I just want to know which http method maps all the above listed functions

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simple way you can say:

1.list():           HTTP Get

2.create():         HTTP Post

3.retrieve():       HTTP Get

4.update():         HTTP Put

5.partial_update(): HTTP Patch

6.destroy():        HTTP Delete

Answer (score 6):

You can see Django Rest Framework code and see in [routers.py](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py) file methods mapping, e.g. in SimpleRouter:

- GET: list() and retrieve()
- POST: create()
- PUT: update()
- PATCH: partial_update()
- DELETE: destroy()